# Forwarding functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a small wrapper for a database API to add custom functionality.

The `view` function I just want to take as it is and not modify, so I tried assigning the function:

```
core.db.view = bucket.view;
```

The function seems to work but there's an HTTP error. If I wrap the function, everything works fine, but I would prefer just assigning the function.

```
core.db.view = function (a, b, c) {
  return bucket.view(a, b, c);
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you need to do `core.db.view = bucket.view.bind(bucket);`?

Comment: See MDN's article on `bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only difference between the two calls below is the context they are executed in:

```
core.db.view = bucket.view;
bucket.view() // 'this' will be bucket
core.db.view() // 'this' will be core.db
```

Solution:

```
core.db.view = bucket.view.bind(bucket);
```

PS: The bind method works similarly to how you wrapped the function yourself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript

```
obj.method();
```

and

```
var m = obj.method; m();
```

are different things. More specifically what is the `this` value during the execution of the body of the method is different in the two cases: in the first case `this` will be `obj`, in the second case `this` will be the global object instead.

A solution is wrapping the method call in a closure:

```
var m = function(){return obj.method()};
```

Comment: That's the solution he has already.  He was looking for a solution that *didn't* involve wrapping it in a new function.

Comment: From the text seems to me s/he didn't understand **WHY** just assigning the function didn't work. Also `bind` is basically wrapping the function too (returns a new distinct object that forwards the call after setting the context).